# サーバーで稼働させているファイル生成アプリのファイル生成先がローカルPCになる

Tags: node.js, network, nginx, axios

お世話になります。
サーバーとローカルPCのネットワークの関係についてご教示いただけないでしょうか？
現在、nuxt.jsとfirebaseを使って
とある書類の印刷アプリを開発しています。

nuxt.jsのservermiddlewareを使い本体アプリからpdfを生成するためのapiを生やしています。
フォームに入力した内容をaxiosで/api/pdfへとpostし
nuxtのstaticディレクトリ内へhoge.pdfのようにpdfファイルを生成する仕様としております。

アプリのhostは127.0.0.1としています。
portは3100
サーバーのOSはUbuntu 18.04.2 LTS
webサーバーはnginxです。

サーバーでこのような形でアプリを稼働させている際
ローカルPC上で
127.0.0.1:3100で同様のアプリをテストで稼働させていると

pdfの生成先がローカルマシン上のnuxtのstaticディレクトリとなってしまいます。

私自身ネットワークはあまり詳しく無いのですが
私の解釈では127.0.0.1というのはプライベートなipで
外部のマシンと共有される事は無いはずだと考えているのですが違うのでしょうか？

サーバーの127.0.0.1で稼働しているアプリがなぜ
ローカルマシンの127.0.0.1で稼働しているアプリに影響するのでしょうか？

ちなみにローカルの127.0.0.1で稼働するアプリを終了すると
pdfはローカルマシン上はもちろん、サーバー側でもpdfは生成されません。

この辺りネットワークの仕組みとかどうなっているのでしょうか？
ネットワークに詳しい方おられましたら
ご教示お願い出来ますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問中に出てくる「サーバー」はどこに設置されていますか？仮想環境もしくはAWSなどのクラウド環境そのへんの情報も教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
サーバーはGMOのVPSを利用しています。

Comment: 全体像が判りません。　物理的なマシンは何台あって、その上で構築されている仮想環境はどうなっていてとか、"アプリのhostは127.0.0.1"で出てくるアプリは何をするもので、そのアプリが稼働しているホストは何処にある何か、、、などなど訳が判りません。

Comment: 単純に`ローカルPC上で～同様のアプリをテストで稼働`しているから、ではないですか？ / 本番環境はGMOのVPSとして、ローカルでのテストとは具体的にどんなことをしているのでしょうか？本番と同じようにwebサーバを用意してアプリを稼働させている？

Answer (score 0):

回答頂きありがとうございます。

自己解決しました。
原因はaxiosのpostのurlをフルパスで記述していなかった事が原因でした。
element-uiのel-uploadのaction属性なんかはフルパスで記述する必要がなかったので
同じ対応をしてしまっていました。

axiosのpostをフルパスにしていないアプリをサーバーで稼働させた場合
このような現象が起こる事が分かりました。